# Facebook C# SDK v6 - How to force object rescrape?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I read on the facebook documentation ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/612/)) that you can force a rescrape of your object to update it on a user's timeline.

> Updating Objects
>
> When modifying Open Graph objects, you will need to tell Facebook’s
>   scraper to rescrape your page to pull in the updated information.
>   There are a couple different ways to have your object re-scraped.
>
> More automated by using the "scrape=true" POST parameter. Make a POST
>   call to https://graph.facebook.com/?id={id}&scrape=true where {id} is
>   the object id or the url of the object. The response is a JSON object
>   with the data scraped for the url.

So how wold you go about this using the C# SDK?

Thanks in advance,
Chad

EDIT: I tried the following as a quick and dirty test:

```
        Dim fbData As FacebookSDKInterface = New FacebookSDKInterface()
        Dim fb As Facebook.FacebookClient = New Facebook.FacebookClient(fbData.FacebookAccessToken)

        Dim fbURL As String = NavigateURL() & "?ID=" & GetPathFromDyno(e.Keys(0))

        Dim dicFBPostParams As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        dicFBPostParams.Add("id", fbURL)
        dicFBPostParams.Add("scrape", "true")


        fb.Post(dicFBPostParams)
```

But I got this error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch. at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture) at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index) at Facebook.FacebookClient.ToDictionary(Object parameters, IDictionary`2& mediaObjects, IDictionary`2& mediaStreams) at Facebook.FacebookClient.PrepareRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType, Stream& input, Boolean& containsEtag, IList`1& batchEtags) at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType) at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String path, Object parameters) at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(Object parameters) at Incite.Modules.TheDynoRoom.MyGarage.dtlDyno_ItemUpdated(Object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Chad\Documents\Incite Systems\Development\Web Sites\DNN_Dyno\DesktopModules\Incite\The Dyno Room\Controls\MyGarage.ascx.vb:line 1156
```

Comment: try dictionary of string,object

Comment: Ah, that worked, thank you...but now I get a "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path" error. So to acheive the equivalent of a POST call to "https://graph.facebook.com/?id=00000000000000&scrape=true", would would be the "path" parameter to pass to the post method? the id and scrape values are passed in via the parameters, and the "https://graph.facebook.com/" part of the path are implied or already built in right?

Comment: which version of the sdk are you using? this was fixed in v6.0.14 https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/issues/156

Comment: I'll try that. I have 6.0.10. I assume you just pass empty string for path then?

Comment: you can't pass empty string in 6.0.10 u need to be at least on 6.0.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prabir was correct. Updated to the latest release...and it worked! Thanks @prabir!